# Capture if else conditions from string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Suppose below is my input string

```
IF[Category Name]=="CPU"then'YES'elseif [Category Name]=="RAM" then 'YES' else 'NO'end
```

using regular expression i want to obtain all the if and elseif conditions as below

```
[Category Name]=="CPU"then'YES'
[Category Name]=="RAM" then 'YES'
```

conditions

1. there can be any number of spaces in between
2. ignore case
3. any comparison operators like '=,==,>=,<=,>,<,<>'

this is what I have tried but it doesn't group the results correctly

```
if(?:(?! +(?:if|else|end)).)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern and extract the value of the first capturing group:

```
\b(?:if|else(?:if)?)\b(.*?)(?=\b(else(if)?|end)\b)
```

**Caution:** It works if the following conditions are met:

1. Non of the following words exists within quotes as a whole word: `if`, `else`, `elseif`, or `end`
2. There are not any nested if-else statements